# "Recursion depth exceeded allowed limit." Breeze.js

Tags: breeze

I receive the "Recursion depth exceeded allowed limit." error when I make a breeze where condition with more than 100 conditions.

My code is

```
$(list).each(function () {
  if (pred === undefined) {
    pred = entity_ODL.create("id", "==", this.id());
  }
  else {
     pred = pred.or("id", "==", this.id());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

More than 100 conditions on a query? That sounds warning bells to me. If I were you, I'd really have a good look at what needs to be accomplished and if the current method is indeed the correct way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The limit doesn't especially surprise me. So I think that your best bet would be to create and execute multiple queries each with less that 100 conditions and then concatenate the results.  See the Q.all method for combining multiple async methods into a single callback.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specifically say, but I believe the error is actually occurring on the server side and not a breeze specific problem.

You can fix it by adding/changing the attribute of the method in your ApiController.

i.e.

```
[HttpGet]
[BreezeQueryable(MaxNodeCount = 10000)]
public IQueryable<EquipmentSearchView> EquipmentSearchView()
{
...
```